# Spartacus new Catalog with products on electronics template

Tags: spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm new to Spartacus and I'm not sure what is the best option for creating a new website with the template of electronics page, but my own catalog and products. I tried creating new website in /backoffice WCMS section and then tried to use the same properties as the electronics page has, but I didn't get it to work.

I also tried this and it didn't work for me: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/04/07/create-new-page-in-spartacus/

Is it possible to give me ideas or ways on how to do it correctly or maybe some basic steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need all of the sample data to create a new CMS website reusing the electronics page template. Have a look at the [spartacussampledata](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacussampledata-extension/) extension for examples on how we do this.
2. After, you'll need to update [Spartacus configuration module](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/reference-app-structure/) (3.2 and above) or Spartacus configuration in older versions to reference your new website.